# Python Input function not Working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, terminal, vscode-code-runner

```
    balance = 100
    print('Current Balance: ', balance)
    while balance > 0:
        print('1. WITHDRAW')
        print('2. DEPOSIT')
        choice = input("Select an option... ")
        if (choice == 1):
            print('1')
        elif (choice == 2):
            print('2')
        else:
            print('test')
```

When I run the code with the code runner extension the code shows in the terminal however when it gets to the input function it freezes like its asking me to input some data however I cant eve type a number or letter.

This is what the terminal shows...

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\bowen\Desktop\CSE 120\PROJECT 3\main.py"
Current Balance:  100
1. WITHDRAW
2. DEPOSIT
Select an option...
```

Comment: "owever when it gets to the input function it freezes like its asking me to input some data however I cant eve type a number or letter." Please be specific. Did you try clicking the terminal window and pressing either the `1` key or the `2` key? When you do so, do you see the corresponding symbol? In general, do you see a blinking cursor in that window? Are you able to make the code run properly directly from the terminal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Code Runner** shows results in OUTPUT and doesn't accept inputs by default. Add

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

in Settings.json, then you can input data.

Comment: How to install Python code runner in VS Code?

Answer (score 13):

the problem is not of python but of vscode, you have to enable one setting,

1. do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or just open settings
2. search for code runner run in terminal
3. enable it

Answer (score 7):

Step-by-step:

1. Click on **extensions** and make sure **Code Runner** is installed.
2. Go to **File > Preferences > Settings** [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>]
3. Type `Code Runner` in the **search bar**
4. Scroll down and check on `Code-runner: Run In Terminal`

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just a copy-paste from random_hooman's answer below? Dated from Sep 15, 2021 btw