# EOFError: EOF when reading a line How can I fix this coe?

Tags: python, eoferror

```py
def get_days_in_birthday_month():
    date = input("Enter your Birthday (dd/mm/yyyy):")
    x = date.split("/")
    month = x[1];
    if(month=="1" or month=="3" or month=="5" or month=="7" or month=="8" or month=="10" or month=="12" ):
        return "31";
    elif (month=="4" or month=="6"  or month=="9" or month=="11"):
        return "30";
    else:
        return "29";

    
days = get_days_in_birthday_month()
print("The number of days is:" + days)
```

```
    ***Error***
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "__tester__.python3", line 23, in <module>
        print("The number of days is: " + get_days_in_birthday_month())
      File "__tester__.python3", line 8, in get_days_in_birthday_month
        date = input("Enter your Birthday (dd/mm/yyyy):")
      File "__tester__.python3", line 3, in input
        s = __saved_input__(prompt)
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I got eof error for this code and I don't know how to fix it .
How can I fix this eof error to get this code right?

Comment: print("The number of days is: " + get_days_in_birthday_month()) -> this line appears in the error traceback, but not in the code. Please make sure the question contains the exact code that produces the error

Comment: You might get this error if you type the EOF (end of file) sequence at the input prompt; this would be `CTRL+D` in a Linux or MacOs terminal, `CTRL+Z` followed by enter in a Windows terminal (I think).

Comment: If you are using VSCode, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69187041/5320906) may help

Comment: This code worked for me... I introduced "19/03/1998" and got: "Enter your Birthday (dd/mm/yyyy):19/03/1998 \n The number of days is:29" this makes sense because "03" != "3"