# why am I not able to input the data

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input

I was learning python as a beginner through YouTube. In the video I was following the output was shown in terminal, but not in my case. It doesn't even accept taking in data for the variable. What am I doing wrong?

the code was simply :

```
a = input("Enter name")
print(a)
```

but the output would only show the text, but wont let me type the input

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, please copy and paste into the question as text

Comment: just type something in terminal and then hit enter

Comment: how are you running your code? are you using an IDE or are you calling your program from the terminal?

Comment: @sahasrara62 i tried to input the txt "hello", but it threw some error,
hello : The term 'hello' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,   
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.     
At line:1 char:1
+ hello
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hello:String) [], CommandNotF  
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: assuming you have your code saved in a file named `myfile.py`  and that you have a terminal open:  go to the folder where you have your program and type `python myfile.py` to execute your program. You will see the text "Enter name" then just introduce a name and press enter

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i m using vscode as ide, not through terminal

Comment: what extension are you using to run python inside vscode? if ou are using coderunner take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186311/python-input-function-not-working-in-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

You code should be working fine. Maybe, you are trying to edit the text `Enter name`, which is not possible in the terminal.

Try typing the name and pressing `<Enter>` when the text `Enter name` shows up.

You can test it here: https://pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u20054_20A4kkNBC961W5aZFb2NJCBW_v0.py
But keep in mind that this is running on the web, not in a terminal, so it will show an input box in which you can input the data.

Comment: just found out the path pointed out to a directory in C: , but my file was in drive D:...thnx for the recommending me the sandbox site tho

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please ensure that you installed [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension.

Then you can run the file by click **Run Python File** button.

[image]

If you install the code-runner extension and use Run Code button. You need to add the following code to your settings.json (shortcuts "Ctrl+shift+P" and type Preferences : Open User Settings):

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

By the way, read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) is a good choice.